# Pylance reportGeneralyTypeIssues expected class type but received "SQLAlchemy"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask-sqlalchemy, pylance

I am looking for a way to fix this error message from pylance in conjunction with SQLAlchemy in Visual Studio Code. What can I write in a stub file to make this error go away?

**The code**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

...

class Post(app_db.Model): # <=== error
    id = app_db.Column(app_db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = app_db.Column(app_db.String(50))
```

**The error report:**

```
{
    "resource": "/Users/andreclaassen/Projects/notion-automation/notion-kpi/notionkpi/__init__.py",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "code": {
        "value": "reportGeneralTypeIssues",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/master/docs/configuration.md",
            "path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/master/docs/configuration.md",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "github.com"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Expected class type but received \"SQLAlchemy\"",
    "source": "Pylance",
    "startLineNumber": 23,
    "startColumn": 12,
    "endLineNumber": 23,
    "endColumn": 18
}
```

Comment: What is the complete information from Pylance displayed in the VS Code terminal?

Comment: What I have is this:


Expected class type but received "SQLAlchemy"
Expected class type but received "Marshmallow"
```

Comment: -Does the code execute as expected? If it does not affect the execution of the code, you could turn off this information in the settings.